# Grails. Saving updates to an object made in session scope does not work. LazyInitializationException

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a straightforward use case, which does not work.

The `resume` action gets an object from database, stores it in session scope and then renders a view which displays a form where the object's fields can be changed. The save processes the form submit and needs to persist the updated object. The domain object is made of primitive and complex fields. The issue has to do with grails session scope, hibernate persistence session, which has been discussed in other threads, but it just does not seem to work. Reading the docs and other discussions, it seems that I should be using `attach()`, but it does not work and results in the `LazyInitialization` exception below. If I don't do the `merge()`, I  get the same exception:

```
could not initialize proxy - no Session. Stacktrace follows:
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at com.toxservices.ApplicationController$_saveRequestForService_closure1$$EOB7zOh6.doCall(ApplicationController.groovy:302)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:573)
```

Using `merge()` does not result in an exception, but it does not seem to work since the object's values are not updated in the database. I can see the updated values come in with the form submit, the save methods does not error out, but the values are not updated.

What am I doing wrong? This seems like a very typical use case, so its very puzzling. Sample code is below. I scrubbed it to only leave the relevant pieces.

```
def resume(){
    def rfs = Rfs.get(params.id)
    session.rfs = rfs
    render(view: "index", model: [rfs:rfs]) 
}
//index presents a form where Rfs can be updated and form re-submitted

def save() {
    def rfs
    if(session.rfs){
        rfs = session.rfs
        captureFormData(rfs, params)
        saveRfs(rfs, true)
    }
}

private def saveRfs(rfs, merge) {
//      if(!rfs.isAttached()){
//          rfs.attach()
//      }

    if(merge){
        rfs = rfs.merge()
    }

    Rfs.withTransaction {

        rfs.product.hAddress.address.save()
        rfs.product.mAddress.address.save()
        rfs.product.sContact.address.save()
        rfs.product.tContact.address.save()
        rfs.product.mContact.address.save()

        rfs.product.hAddress.save()
        rfs.product.mAddress.save()
        rfs.product.sContact.save()
        rfs.product.tontact.save()
        rfs.product.mContact.save()

        rfs.product.X.save()
        rfs.product.save()  
        ...
        rfs.save()
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your approach looks non-conventional. Anyway, can you try moving the logic for `attach()` inside `withTransaction` block and comment out `merge()` logic.

Comment: If first approach fails, then try moving the `withTransaction` block to `save()` wrapping the `if` block. Although, there is a better way to write the logic in controller.

Comment: is there a reason you don't just submit the Rfs.id from view (via form hidden field) back to save(), and use Rfs.get() again vs saving the rfs in session?

Comment: LOL. @user2264997 just mentioned you my better way... :)

Comment: Thank you both. The method recommended by user226* worked. I am not sure why I did not think of it. Maybe out of habit that carrying  state across multiple requests is generally done via session scope, so I was set on doing it this way. Having to query for object again by id during save feels strange since I already had it at the beginning of my `resume` action. It does work, so I am happy. @dmahapatro Putting attach inside the withTransaction block did not do it. I am still curious about getting the original approach to work since it just feels that it should work, albeit it is less urgent.

Comment: Now that you confirmed @user2264997 suggested approach works, I can say that my suggested approach would fail because `rfs` is no way related to hibernate session inside `saveRfs` because you are fetching it from request's session instead of doing a `get(id)` and fetching it from hibernate's `SessionFactory`.I was trying you to test for me, is it possible to attach the object back to session even if it is not retrieved from a different hibernate session. Add your current approach as an answer or ask @user226* to add and accept it. :)